# Determine the screw axis of a $3D$ rigid motion given by $F(x)=Ax+c$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rigid-transformation

> Determine the screw axis of a $3D$ rigid motion given by $F(x)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\\end{pmatrix}x+\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\\\end{pmatrix}$

Characteristic polynomial is $P(x)=-(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)^2$

So I found the eigenvalues were $\lambda_1=1, \lambda_2=-1$ which had multiplicity $2$ for the matrix

Then the eigenvectors are $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\\end{pmatrix}$

And $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\\end{pmatrix}$ and $v_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\\end{pmatrix}$

I'm not really sure what to do from here, I thought the axis should correspond to one of these $3$ lines given by the eigenvectors, and that $\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\\\end{pmatrix}$ should then lie on one of the lines. But that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determinant is $1$ so the matrix is a pure rotation, with no reflection.

The eigenvectors determine the reference system in which the action of the matrix is  a stretching along the axes: in that reference the matrix becomes diagonal.

The product of the eigenvalues shall be $1$ as well. In this case they are $1, -1, -1$.

Clearly a vector along the rotation axis shall remain the same, and that is $(1,1,0)$ which is at $\pi /4$ in the $x,y$ plane.

The rotation is reversing the direction of the $z$ axis: so it is a rotation of $\pi$.
This will sweep the position of the $x$ and $y$ axes, which in fact is what the matrix does.

*--- note in reply to your comment  ---*

A [rigid rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) must have at least one eigenvalue $=1$.
If it has two at $1$, then it must have all three ad it is a zero rotation matrix, otherwise the determinant is not one,
and it is not a "pure" ("rigid body") rotation, but contains some stretching and/or reflection.

Comment: So the axis of rotation is always the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $1$? What if $1$ isn't an eigenvalue? Say eigenvalues are $i,i,-1$? Or if there are $2$ eigenvectors associated to $\lambda=1$?

Comment: added note to reply: we are just speaking of real eigenvalues, of course.

Comment: @G Cab So how do I find the screw axis? I have a line fixed by the rotation, but the translation part moves that line.

Comment: and the line is translated parallel to itself ..

Comment: @G Cab But that translated line is going to vectors which aren't fixed to the line? I don't understand.

Comment: ohi,  wait a minute ! what is the context of your problem, linear analysis, physics or else ? what is your definition of **screw** axis ? and what is $x$ ??

Comment: The screw axis is a line which is fixed by a rigid motion $F$. $x$ is just an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: I see, you are talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_axis) right ?

Comment: Yes. But I'm not sure how to find that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115630/discussion-between-g-cab-and-acoloredreptile).